# Empty RecyclerView from JSON Data

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

thanks for all the help so far. This is a bit odd question from me. I am making a network request to fetch data from server and updating the UI with the json strings. I have done the json parsing correctly and printed the result in my log cat like this:

```
11-17 22:57:02.143 25111-25111/com.billionusers.tingting D/MyReviewsFragment: FAN Lib My Reviews Response is:   {"success":true,"reviews":[{"_id":"5a0ef724b004b53e48eafaf6","updatedAt":"2017-11-17T14:50:12.700Z","createdAt":"2017-11-17T14:50:12.700Z","for":"5a0d90b8f690f625df370bb6","by":"5a0aa8f7aecfbc47838fb89b","body":"Lorem Ipsum","__v":0}]}
```

I have used a model class to save the reviews and created the adapter from recyclerview procedure. My model class contains the name, image, time and body of the review data from server.

Here is my adapter code:

```
public class ReviewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyReviewsHolder> {

private final Context context;
private List<Reviews> itemsList;

public ReviewsAdapter(Context context, List<Reviews> itemsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
}

@Override
public MyReviewsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_reviews_item_layout, parent, false);
    return new MyReviewsHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyReviewsHolder viewholder, int position) {
    Reviews reviews = itemsList.get(position);
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(reviews.getReviewerImg())
            .into(viewholder.reviewerProfileImg);
    viewholder.reviewerNameTV.setText(reviews.getReviewerName());
    viewholder.reviewTimeTV.setText(reviews.getReviewTime());
    viewholder.reviewBodyTV.setText(reviews.getReviewBody());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (itemsList == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return itemsList.size();
}
}
```

In my fragment, I have initialized the views and fields like:

```
private TextView dummy;
private RecyclerView my_reviews_recyclerView;

private List<Reviews> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
private ReviewsAdapter adapter;

private boolean success;

public MyReviewsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_reviews, container, false);

    dummy = view.findViewById(R.id.dummy);

    my_reviews_recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_reviews_recyclerView);
    my_reviews_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    my_reviews_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    fetchMyReviews();

    return view;
}
```

Code for making the network request. I have also done json parsing here and tried updating the UI with data but recyclerview shows empty state.

Here's the network and UI code:

```
AndroidNetworking.get(Constants.GET_MY_REVIEWS_ENDPOINT)
            .addHeaders("x-access-token", token)
            .setTag("Get My Reviews")
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "FAN Lib My Reviews Response is: \t" + response.toString());

                    try {
                        JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject("");
                        success = (boolean) object.get("success");

                        JSONArray reviewsArray = object.getJSONArray("reviews");
                        for (int i = 0; i < reviewsArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject body = reviewsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String revId = body.getString("_id");
                            String revTime = body.getString("createdAt");
                            String revFor = body.getString("for");
                            String revBy = body.getString("by");
                            String revMsgBody = body.getString("body");

                            // TODO: 11/17/2017  Get Reviewer Details

                            //Reviews reviews = new Reviews("", "Demo User", revMsgBody, revTime);
                            Reviews reviews = new Reviews();
                            reviews.setReviewerName("Abhiram Labhani");
                            reviews.setReviewerImg("");
                            reviews.setReviewBody(revMsgBody);
                            reviews.setReviewTime(revTime);
                            itemsList.add(reviews);

                            adapter = new ReviewsAdapter(getActivity(), itemsList);
                            my_reviews_recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                            if (adapter.getItemCount() > 0){
                                dummy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Adapter size is:\t" + adapter.getItemCount());
                            } else {
                                dummy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                Log.d(TAG, "Adapter size is:\t" + adapter.getItemCount());
                            }

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError anError) {

                }
            });
```

Could someone point out what I'm missing as I don't know where the problem is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the error:

```
JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject("");
                        success = (boolean) object.get("success");
                        JSONArray reviewsArray = object.getJSONArray("reviews");
```

Why are you using empty jsonobject from response?  Use it directly :

```
                    success = (boolean) response.get("success");
                    JSONArray reviewsArray = response.getJSONArray("reviews");
```

Comment: sure, no problem : ) glad to help you. Don't forget to mark the question as resolved

Comment: Yh..in 59 seconds..SO is funny

Answer (score 0):

try to troubleshoot first,

1. check if the json you fetching is not null
2. from there, you can now check if the json you are fetching is the problem or the adapter.

Comment: I have logged the json response at the start of this question. It is coming correctly. Please have another look.